# I have problems when I close the Connection and then try to login again

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a login form and getting to check it in the MySQL database. If it is successful, I am opening another frame. But when I try to go back to the login frame, even If the data I inputted was right, the login always fails.

I tried to close the connection but that is the reason why it fails. When I try to remove the `connection.close()`, my program is working.

```
switch (bean.getUserLevel()) {
case 0:     
frame.dispose();
new OwnerGUI(bean).build();
break;
....
```

This is the code where I try to open another frame and when I go back to the login frame, it fails.

If I try to use this code

```
ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
```

My program wouldn't work properly. But if I let the connection open, I think it is not a good practice. So I'm trying to close the connection and open it again until needed.

This is the getConnection code to better see where I went wrong.

```
public Connection getConnection(){
if(conn == null) {
  if(openConnection()){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Opened");
   return conn;
  } else {
     System.err.println("Error");
     return null;
  }
} else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Already Open");
      return conn;
}
```

Comment: When a login fails, do you get any error message?

Comment: I don't get error message. I just get the checking that login fails

Comment: I'll edit your tag to draw more attention.

Comment: Please post a [mre].